# How to re-install of GPG4win and start from scratch?

Tags: gnupg, reinstall, gpg4win, kleopatra

It appears that I used GPG4win many years ago.

Now I want to use it again -- with no relationship to any earlier use, which I do not care about. I want to verify `electrum.exe` via ThomasV's signature.

I downloaded GPG4win anew but Kleopatra keeps asking for my original passphrase no matter what.

Why can't I obliterate any existing gpg/Kleopatra memory of my earlier use--like reinstalling a new Windows.

I tried uninstall of gpg, etc.

Comment: Check `%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Roaming\gnupg` there the old files should be located. Close all WinPG related programs and rename that directory to start over new.

Comment: Thanks, Robert.  That worked just fine.

Answer (score 0):

Robert's comment to rename `%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Roaming\gnupg` worked fine.